# Finding maximum +ve/-ve values of a variable in Matlab? How do I return a 0 if variable does not go below 0 or vice versa?

Tags: if-statement, max, minimum

Thank you in advance for the help. I'm having some trouble with the 2nd half of my question on Matlab so I would really appreciate some help. I'm sure there's a simple answer but for some reason I just can't figure it out!

What I would like to do is find the maximum positive and maximum negative values of my variable in Matlab but, if the variable does not go below 0, I would like my script to return a 0 and vice versa. It is easy enough to find the maximum positive and maximum negative values if my variable goes both above and below zero but I'm having trouble writing a script to return a 0 when the values in my variable never go below 0. Below is the script I've tried but the problem is that the second C_FE overwrites the previous maximum value with a 0.

```
if C_FE>0
    C_Flex = max(C_FE)
else C_Flex = 0
end
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this and I apologise if I'm missing the obvious!

Thanks,
Ramesh